# aws-sdk for RDS nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-rds

I need to start and stop an instance of RDS from a nodejs script.

But I read the AWS documentation but I didn't see how to do it.

I have installed aws-sdk and I'm trying to use it like this:

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const test = new aws.RDS({
    apiVersion: "XXXX",
    accessKeyId: "",
    secretAccessKey: "",
    region: "XXXXX",
    endpoint: "XXXXXX"
});
```

is there a better way to implement this functionality?

Thanks in advance,
Javier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After initializing the Service like you did, you can call `startDBInstance`

```
var params = {
  DBInstanceIdentifier: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
};
test.startDBInstance(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

and `stopDBInstance`:

```
var params = {
  DBInstanceIdentifier: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  DBSnapshotIdentifier: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
test.stopDBInstance(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Refer to docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/RDS.html#startDBInstance-property